# Insert } to complete ClassBody

Tags: java, class, insert

Sorry if I seem dumb but I'm new to java. I get this error when I type this code I've been working on

```
public class Test 
{

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a test");

    }

    {
        System.out.println("also");
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'd really suggest that first you open a book about Java or try to follow a beginner tutorial.

Comment: Your question title is your answer.

Comment: What do you expect the behavior of your code to be?

Comment: You need an IDE which takes care of indentation and matching brackets...

Comment: @Sanjay: Okay, but at least a text editor that can show mismatched brackets.

Comment: @Thilo I said in a general context, to find mismatched brackets, IDE is the best :D

Answer (score 2):

A basic tutorial like this might help a lot.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_syntax.htm

For this example, try this

```
public class Test {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    System.out.println("This is a test");
    System.out.println("also");

    }
}
```

Code should be inside some method.

Comment: "Code should be inside some method." Not necessarily. You can put code into initializer blocks.

Comment: @Thilo agreed. I was about to mention that, but skipped it deliberately as it might have confused him more.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't close your class properly:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is a test");
  }

  {
    System.out.println("also");
  }
}
```

Also, where you put `System.out.println("also");` you need to define it as a method, like this:

```
public void someMethod() {
  System.out.println("also");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issues are:

1) Making sure your curly braces match

2) Making sure everything inside of your curly braces is legal Java

```
// Bad
public class Test {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("This is a test");

}

{
    System.out.println("also");

}

// OK
public class Test {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is a test");
    System.out.println("also");
  }

}

// Also OK
public class Test {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("This is a test");
    also ();
  }

  public static void also () {
   System.out.println("also");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, as it is an object oriented programming language, everything termed under and object.
An object contains set of states and behaviors, here the states means fields with values and behaviors means methods. So all included in a class is defenition of an object, so the class only contains variables and methods. In object oriented programming the program flow is based on object interaction, and we can access the **methods** and **variables** in class using the object of the class.

Here you have written the  code

```
   System.out.println();
```

outside the method and it cannot be accessed by any approach, that mean you have to write any executable statement inside a method.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from you code, you are starting a "{" before writing `System.out.println("also");` but you are not closing this one. So it is giving you error.

Either you put it in a method like in your main method :

```
public class Test  {
  public static void main (String[] args)     {         
       System.out.println("This is a test");     
        System.out.println("also"); 
  }
}
```

or if you want to write it in block then :

```
public class Test  {
  public static void main (String[] args)     {         
       System.out.println("This is a test");     
  }
  {
      System.out.println("also"); 
  }
}
```

Such blocks are called instance initialization blocks.

Comment: Yeah I agree if some people say I should pick up a book or look up a tutorial. Im a retard at this stuff lol